# Don't route specific route in Ocelot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ocelot

I have a load balancer/API. This Process runs on 3 ports 5000, 5001 and 5002. Every request that comes in on ports 5000 and 5001 with the base route /api should be routed to the specified hosts. But there is a single controller on port 5002 with the route /page (Just an example name) that shouldn't be forwarded but handled whithin the load balancer/API.

http://localhost:5000/api -> forward 
https://localhost:5001/api -> forward 
https://localhost:5002/page -> Don't forward

So the configuration for the /api route works like expected so I'm not going to include that here. For the /page route I tried:

```json
{
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/secrets",
    "UpstreamScheme": "https",
    "UpstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
            "Host": "localhost",
            "Port": 5002
        }
    ],
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/secrets",
    "DownstreamScheme": "https",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
            "Host": "localhost",
            "Port": 5002
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Is this "load balancer" your Ocelot project?

Comment: Yes, the "load balancer" is my Ocelot project, but it should handle the /page request by itself.

Comment: Then don't define an Ocelot route.  Simply add the controller and make sure your project registers the controllers as a regular ASP.net application.  Then ASP.net will use your controllers as per usual, and anything else goes into the Ocelot middleware.

Comment: I don't think this is true, when I do this I get this error:
Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HMUDL8PEIKCF:00000003, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /page, verb: GET. errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/page, request method: GET

Comment: You need to order your middleware appropriately.  Show your middleware setup.

Comment: I'm sorry for that question. That was just a stupid mistake, because I called app.UseOcelot(), before adding the endpoints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How José Ramírez pointed it out in his comment, the order of the middlewares has to be correct.

In this case, you have to use this order

```cs
app.MapControllers()
app.UseOcelot().Wait()
```